# debian lenny ftp not working?

Tags: debian, ftp

I've installed ftp in my debian lenny virtual server with apt-get install ftp and it uses the archive ftp_0.17-18_amd64.deb. But when I type ftp command into my shell there isn't any response? When I want to connect to a ftp site it's not working? I get not any response? ftp --help gives me this:

```
Aufruf: ftp [ignorierete Kommandozeilenargumente]
oder:  ftp OPTION 
Exit with a status code indicating failure.

  --help     diese Hilfe anzeigen und beenden
  --version  Versionsinformation anzeigen und beenden

BEMERKUNG: Ihre Shell hat möglicherweise eine eigene Version von false, 
welche normalerweise die hier beschriebene Version ersetzt. Bitte greifen Sie
auf die Dokumentation der Shell zurück, um die dort unterstützten Optionen
in Erfahrung zu bringen.

Melden Sie Übersetzungsfehler an 
<translation-team-de@lists.sourceforge.net>, Programmfehler dagegen (auf 
Englisch, mit LC_ALL=C) an <bug-coreutils@gnu.org>.
```

Comment: This is really odd... instead of `ftp`, `/bin/false` is being called. Can you tell us what `ls -la /usr/bin/ftp` gives?

Comment: @Renan: /usr/bin/ftp -> /etc/alternatives/ftp

Comment: /usr/bin/netkit-ftp works and load a ftp but I can't connect to my ftp site. Do I need other prerequisites?

Comment: @David: `ls -l /etc/alternatives/ftp` is also needed (cause it is link to some binary, not final binary Renan wants). And can you attach full log of what you're doing in console with `ftp` including all errors. There is vary general description in your quetion right now?

Comment: @Rush: I don't have physical access to my virtual server, is that what you asked for? I can ftp to my vm but I cannot ftp from my vm? I need to connect to a ftp site from my (remote) vm.

Comment: @Rush: etc/alternatives/ftp -> /usr/bin/netkit-ftp

Comment: Can you `ssh` in and try `update-alternatives --config ftp`?

Comment: @sr_: Es gibt nur 1 Programm, welches ftp bereitstellt
(/usr/bin/netkit-ftp). Nichts zu konfigurieren.

Comment: Please run `export LC_ALL=C` so that we get messages in English. Then show us the output of `type ftp` and `/usr/sbin/update-alternatives --display ftp`. For your trouble with `netkit-ftp`, describe precisely what happens; copy-paste the exact commands you typed and any error message.

Comment: @Gilles: Can I revert it? I was thinking about this but I don't have an english keyboard. Sorry.

Comment: @David `export LC_ALL=C` doesn't change your keyboard settings. It only has an effect in the current shell and applications launched from that shell.